# How to retrieve data from @ xml attribute in PHP

Tags: php, xml

Ok so I am stuck with this xml in PHP stuff. I have gotten pretty far considering its my first 3 hours into XML all together ever in my entire life.

I am having trouble pulling data from a XML thing that has @ in the name. See below (obviously im not going to post the whole XML thing but u can see how i got there below that.

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2010-09
        [reserved] => 6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30
    )

)
```

How i got there:

```
echo $this->General_functions->naked($xml->property[0]->availability->month[0]);
```

General_functions->naked is just a fast function to wrap  and print_r around the given attribute.

My question is, HOW do i get the values inside @attributes cause no matter what i try i cant figure it out. Ive searched the web for a good 45 mins with no real answer.

Thanks in advance.
David

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `attributes()` method to get the results as another class. So, for example, to get the `date` attribute:

```
$myElement->attributes()->date
```

Also note that it's not a string, it's a SimpleXML attribute. If you want to get its actual value, you need to cast it to `string` explicitly:

```
(string)$myElement->attributes()->date
```

Answer (score 1):

Access attributes of an element just as you would elements of an array:

`(string) $xml->property[0]->availability->month[0]['date']`

Edited to add the cast.

Comment: Yea this works too. I still need to add (string) to the front of it though. I thought it returned blank page, but that was a typo of mine.